# Stack pointer moved back but values not loaded to register file?

Tags: stack, mips, cpu, cpu-registers, stack-pointer

What happens when the stack pointer is moved back to its original position but values that were saved in the stack are not loaded back from the memory into the register file? ie values are still present in stack memory when the stack pointer is moved back.

Comment: Nothing happens, and it's perfectly valid to do what you describe. You allocate memory on the stack by moving the stack pointer in one direction, and then you free that memory by moving the stack pointer in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Pointer ($sp) is as the name implies a pointer, points an adress out.

Let's say this is our memory and in the beggining $sp holds the **adress** "0x..01"

> ... | 0x..01 | 0x..02 | 0x..03 | ...

`sw $a0,0($sp)`    # store the **value of $a0** at the first offset of **$sp adress**
 (which is 0x..01 in this example)

`addi $sp,$sp,4`    # moving $sp

Now let's see what do we have. $sp is not pointing 0x..01 anymore because we have changed it in the second line but the value of $a0 is still stored at 0x..01. If we write another sw command after that, the new value will be stored in the new adress of $sp.

**To sum up:** $sp hold the adress of current cell. When you change $sp, you only change where $sp points out.